# How to parse json object in node.js

Tags: json, node.js, mongoose

The following code is not working. How can I get TripNo from json object?

```
model.Gps.find({EmpName:empName}, function(e,o){
        var jsonvar = JSON.stringify(o);
        console.log(jsonvar.TripNo);
    });
```

Schema:

```
var gpsSchema = mongoose.Schema({ 
    EmpName: String, 
    TripNo: String,
    Latitude: String, 
    Longitude : String,
    Timestamp: Date
});
```

Comment: Just call `o.TripNo` should work.

Comment: Why did you stringify it? seems kinda silly.

Answer (score 0):

The data that returns from mongoose should already be an object.  You don't need to parse anything.  You can access the data by doing the following.

```
model.Gps.find({EmpName:empName}, function(e,o){
    var jsonvar = o;
    console.log(jsonvar.TripNo);
});
```

Or just.

```
model.Gps.find({EmpName:empName}, function(e,o){
    console.log(o.TripNo);
});
```